# Como alinhar um elemento de rodapé sempre na base da página?

Tags: html, css, html5

Tenho uma página na qual há uma `div` com vários conteúdos dentro, que se modificam de acordo com o desejo do usuário. Logo abaixo existe um outro `div` que é o Rodapé.

Caso eu coloque um `position: relative`, o rodapé irá adequar sua posição de acordo com o tamanho da página, porém ele não fica "preso" em baixo (sem nenhum espaço até o fim da página) quando a janela do navegador é redimensionada para um tamanho menor.

Já se eu colocar um `position: absolute`, o rodapé irá ficar fixo no fim da página, mas não se adequará ao tamanho da janela.

Mas gostaria de fixar um `bottom: 0px`, semelhante ao que acontece caso eu aplique um `position: absolute`, mas de forma que se o conteúdo da página for maior, o rodapé não sobreponha a página.

Alguém sabe como seria possível fazer isso?

Meu exemplo está [aqui no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/c2jpt2j2/7/).

Comment: Se eu realmente entendi o seu problema, creio que isto resolverá, pelo menos vai eliminar o espaço entre o footer e a borda da página: `*{margin: 0;}`. Coloque no começo do seu css, isto interferirá em todos os elementos da sua página em que o `margin` não estiver especificado.

Comment: Caso já tenha resolvido favor marcar a como resolvido

Answer (score 4):

**Solução com FLEXBOX e VH**

Fiz um **jsfiddle** com a solução perfeita pra seu problema com apenas 4 propriedades css no container de sua aplicação usando `flexbox` e `vh` como unidade relativa, entenda melhor com o código abaixo:

```
<section class="container">
  <main></main>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</section>

.container{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column:
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Isso garante que o `.container` possua sempre a altura exata da viewport e que o `<main></main>` esteja sempre no começo do `.container` e o `.footer` esteja sempre no final, e quando o conteúdo dentro do `<main></main>` ultrapassar as dimensões da viweport, o `.footer` acompanhe o conteúdo sem se sobrepor.

Veja mais aqui nesse **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/viniciusColares/z2sb1voc/1/)**

E neste link um guia sobre **[FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Answer (score 3):

Manter o rodapé sempre na base, quando o conteúdo é menor que a página, e de modo que ajuste sua posição conforme o conteúdo fique maior, pode ser feito usando um elemento `div` como *wrapper* do conteúdo.

Estrutura HTML de exemplo:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        Conteúdo aqui
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <span>Footer</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

E o seguinte CSS:

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body {height:100%;}
.main {
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative; 
    width:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content{   
    width: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;   
}
#footer{    
    background: #3C948B;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; 
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

### [Exemplo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zwg436s/)

<sup>Nota: créditos a meu colega de trabalho Marcos Souza, que aceitou o desafio.</sup>

Comment: A última linha do texto fica escondida atrás do rodapé. "ipsum ac felis(...)".

Comment: Essa era uma boa solução em 2014, mas hj em 2016, suponho que a melhor solução seja FLEXBOX com VH

Answer (score 1):

Solução em jquery onde não há necessidade de alterar parâmetros em outras div ou body, somente na div onde será o footer.
Uso o jquery para calcular a largura do browser, posição e largura do footer, assim sabendo quanto adicionar margin-top a div footer.

```js
function footer_botom() {
var footer_position = $('#footer').offset().top;
var footer_height = $('#footer').height();
var tela_height = $(window).height();
var margin = tela_height-footer_position-footer_height;
$('#footer').css({"margin-top": margin+'px'});}

footer_botom();
$(window).resize(function() {
$('#footer').css({"margin-top": '0px'});
footer_botom();});
```

```css
#footer {background-color:#ccc; width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        Conteúdo aqui
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <span>Footer</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

De uma olhada : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gigio/vpzc7tL3/2/)

Passei para `position : fixed` e `z-index : 10`

O menu permanece junto ao bottom 0px, agora é só ajustar a margin.

Comment: Sua resposta não soluciona o problema, pois apesar do rodapé manter se ao bottom da viewport, quando o conteúdo principal ultrapassa a altura da viewport o rodapé fica sobreposto, não é essa a proposta.

Answer (score -3):

Tente colocar uma altura mínima no conteúdo acima do `footer`.

Exemplo:

```
min-height: 100px
```

Comment: Leonardo, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! O problema de colocar um `min-height` é que você teria que saber de antemão qual o tamanho da página. Além disso, a pergunta é como manter corretamente o `footer` na base do site com a janela pequena.